# Throwing $k$ balls into $n$ bins.

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion, balls-in-bins, coupon-collector

I have the following question:

Throwing $k$ balls into $n$ bins. What is the probability that exactly $z$ bins are not empty?

I thought about something like: 
$$\Pr(z)=\frac{n! z^{k-z}}{n^k (n-z)!},$$
but this is not correct.

Another idea is: $\Pr(bin ~empty)=(1-1/n)^k$, $\Pr(bin ~Not ~empty)=1-(1-1/n)^k$, so:

$$\Pr(z)=(\Pr(bin ~empty))^{n-z}(\Pr(bin ~Not ~empty))^{z}\cdot A$$

So, how to obtain the $A$?

Thanks!

Comment: Special case $z=n$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174674/if-n-balls-are-thrown-into-k-bins-what-is-the-probability-that-every-bin-gets-a

Comment: But notice, $z\le k$.

Comment: I agree that $z\leq k$, but what's your point? The case $z=n$ is relevant if $n\leq k$.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. But I need the general case, not the special one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that at most $r$ particular bins are not empty is $(r/n)^k$. Thus by inclusion–exclusion the probability that exactly $z$ particular bins are not empty is

$$
\sum_{j=0}^z(-1)^j\binom zj\left(\frac{z-j}n\right)^k=\frac{z!}{n^k}\left\{k\atop z\right\}\;,
$$

where $\displaystyle\left\{k\atop z\right\}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Since there are $\displaystyle\binom nz$ ways of selecting $z$ particular bins, the desired probability is

$$
\binom nz\frac{z!}{n^k}\left\{k\atop z\right\}=\frac{n!}{(n-z)!n^k}\left\{k\atop z\right\}\;.
$$

You can also derive this result by noting that there are $n^k$ outcomes in total, and the favourable outcomes are characterized by a partition of the set of $k$ balls into $z$ non-empty subsets (of which there are $\displaystyle\left\{k\atop z\right\}$ ) and then $n(n-1)\cdots(n-z+1)$ choices where to place each subset.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder why it is not the simple answer shown below.
Choose z bins(any), put 1 ball each in those bins, then randomly put balls in those z bins.

The required prob. is nCz*(z/n)^(k-z)

Comment: The events are dependent... You can't just multiply by nCz. I.e., you have many overlapping sets of bins. You can check it by summing your proposition over $z\in [1,...,k]$ and will see that it won't get 1, but a huge number...