# Infrequent fail of the popular parameter estimators, having several beta-distributed random variables to be estimated

Tags: probability-distributions, parameter-estimation, beta-function, digamma-function

I have a project in which there exist $N$ Beta-distributed Random variables each of which should be estimated, having a sample for each of them. The sample domain is $\{0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9\}$ and the samples are similar to the following sets
\begin{align*}
&S_{1}=\{0.1,0.3,0.3,0.7\}\\
&S_{2}=\{0.3,0.3,0.9\}\\
&S_{3}=\{0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9\}\\
&S_{4}=\{0.3,0.5\}\\
&...\\
&S_{i}=\{0.3\}\\
&...\\
&S_{j}=\{0.1,0.1\}\\
&...\\
&S_{N-3}=\{0.5,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.9,0.9\}\\
&S_{N-2}=\{0.3,0.3,0.5\}\\
&S_{N-1}=\{0.5,0.5,0.7\}\\
&S_{N}=\{0.1,0.5,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9\}
\end{align*}
Each of them is a sample (containing observation(s)), related to a separate Beta distributed random variable. For estimating the corresponding Beta random variables, I take advantage of the well-known estimators, introduced in general resources such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution):
\begin{align*}
&\text{Method of Moments}:\\
&\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i\\
&\bar{v}=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{(X_i-\bar{x})^2}\\\\
&\hat{\alpha}=\bar{x}\left(\frac{\bar{x}(1-\bar{x})}{\bar{v}}-1\right),\text{if }\bar{v}<\bar{x}(1-\bar{x})\\
&\hat{\beta}=(1-\bar{x})\left(\frac{\bar{x}(1-\bar{x})}{\bar{v}}-1\right),\text{if }\bar{v}<\bar{x}(1-\bar{x})\\\\
&\text{Maximum Likelihood Estimator}\\
&\hat{G}_X=\prod_{i=1}^N{X_i^{\frac{1}{N}}}\\
&\hat{G}_{1-X}=\prod_{i=1}^N{(1-X_i)^{\frac{1}{N}}}\\\\
&\hat{\alpha}\approx\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\hat{G}_X}{2\left(1-\hat{G}_{X}-\hat{G}_{1-X}\right)}\text{if }\hat{\alpha}>1\\
&\hat{\beta}\approx\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\hat{G}_{1-X}}{2\left(1-\hat{G}_{X}-\hat{G}_{1-X}\right)}\text{if }\hat{\beta}>1
\end{align*}
Most of the mentioned random variables are estimated by the above techniques. However, in (non-common) situations like $S_i$ or $S_j$, in which the variance of the sample is zero, the well-known estimators fail in estimation (having zero in denominator).

Briefly speaking, the question is how to estimate the parameters of the Beta distribution, when the sample variance is zero.

Comment: What do you think a sample with variance zero *looks like*?

Comment: And what is the probability that a Beta distribution produces three times the same value?

Comment: The point is that in situations where assuming a Beta distribution is sensible, this will never happen. The situation you describe seems especially ill-suited to Beta distributions.

Comment: Sorry but your question asks about one-point samples. If you have a different situation in mind, please modify the question.

Comment: The question is edited and the comments are removed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a systematic reason why the estimators don't work for zero variance. The mode is at $(\alpha-1)/(\alpha+\beta-2)$; you can use arbitrarily high values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to attain a given mode, and the higher you make them, the higher the probability density at the mode. So there's no pair of parameters with maximum likelihood in this case. You'd need a prior that decays sufficiently quickly at high $\alpha$ and $\beta$ values to make any sense out of such a situation.

Comment: I agree that estimators like MLE are not inherently proposed for zero-varianced samples. I also, have tried to provide such estimations like what you proposed. However, those estimations were very tastes-base. I liked to find another estimator that can propose some systematic estimation. My project is a scientific one and tastes-base estimations are not suggested for scientific papers.\begin{align*}&\text{I apologize, because, my time is rigidly restricted and I am leaving my lab. So, kindly thanks for your reply, in advance.}\end{align*}

Comment: @hossayni: I'm afraid everything you can do in this situation will be "taste-based" (nice rhyme :-). You simply don't have any information to make an informed estimate. You could take a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366491/magic-8-ball-problem/1366584#1366584) for another example of a minimum of information being needed to overcome initial ignorance. My suggestion would be: a) Rethink whether this setup is the best possible. b) If the answer is yes, and you really, *really* need these estimates, try to come up with a sensible prior (e.g. from earlier trials).

Comment: P.S.: I don't know how you managed to change the font in that comment, but it looks like it messed up the formatting -- the comments are bleeding into the sidebar (at least in my browser).

Comment: Sorry for delay considering the massive scientific burden on my shoulder these days. Thank you very much for the answer. However, I hope that among several miscellaneous existing estimators, one of them can assist me in these zero-variance cases.

Comment: About the initial ignorance, it is not always the problem. For example in the cases which my observation set is $S_j=\{0.1,0.1\}$ (2 observations) the estimator cannot estimate whereas they are able to estimate the observation set $S_4=\{0.3,0.5\}$ (again 2 observation). It means that (at least in those cases) the problem is more distribution of the observed samples rather than ignorance itself.

Comment: @hossayni: Yes, I didn't mean to imply otherwise.

Comment: About the style, since it almost did not occurred meaningful changes in my display I did not understand. But, now, unfortunately there is no option for edit.