# Probability of having an empty location

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

There are $D$ different kinds of candy, and $C$ children come to buy them. Each child purchases one package of candy. What is the probability that a given variety of candy is chosen by no child?

I am thinking of this as, there are $k$ locations(Candies) in which $n$ items(Children) are being hashed to. What is the probability that one of the locations have nothing hashed to it?

I also already know that the expected number of kinds of candy chosen by no child is
     $D(1-(1/D))^C$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174674/if-n-balls-are-thrown-into-k-bins-what-is-the-probability-that-every-bin-gets-a

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the expected number of kinds chosen by no child is $D(1-\frac 1D)^C$ you can use the linearity of expectation to conclude that the chance one given candy is chosen by no child is $(1-\frac 1D)^C$ because each kind of candy has the same probability not to be chosen.

Usually the argument goes the other way.  Pick a particular candy.  The chance that one child doesn't pick it is $(1-\frac 1D)$  The chance that all the children don't pick it is the product of $C$ of these, $(1-\frac 1D)^C$.