# Distributing balls into bins for large numbers: approximating probabilities

Tags: approximation, stirling-numbers, balls-in-bins

Distributing $n$ balls into $m$ bins with $n > m$, I want to calculate the probability that at least one box will be empty. If I'm not mistaken, that should be

$$p_{m} = 1 - \frac{m! S_n^{(m)}}{m^n}$$

My challenge here is, that I need to compute these probabilities in my software with $n \in [100, 5000]$. More specifically, $n$ is an input parameter from the user, and I perform a binary search to determine the smallest $m$ such that $p_m >= P$ for a threshold $P$ also given by the user. Currently, I simulate it, which is neither really efficient, nor really pretty. I was wondering whether I could also compute (or approximate) $p_m$, without calculating it naively using the formula above. I know about the approximation of factorials (Stirling's approximation), but I didn't have much luck finding approximations for Stirling numbers, but maybe there are already approximations out there for "distributing balls into bins" problems?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174695 has an explicit formula that does not involve Stirling numbers and I believe approximating the binomial coefficients with Stirlings formula might do fine. If you don't like this, another idea is to use the effect of Poissonization, see for example, https://dataorigami.net/blogs/napkin-folding/127970947-poissonization-of-multinomials

Comment: Thanks! I tried both out and going with the inclusion-exclusion formula worked very well with a library for large numbers such as GNU GMP, so that I don't need to approximate after all.